# Survivor space changing, why that?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

As noted in the oracle java GC basic [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) when any minor GC is triggered all object located in S0 sirvivor space (if any) are moved into S1 sirvivor space or vice verca. It seems strange to me, to say the least. To perform the operation the GC waste a JVM resources to moving objects from `Si` to `Sj`, `i!=j, i,j` are from `{1, 2}`. May I not follow the actual purpose of that operation... Couldn't anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Because objects are marked in the `Eden` and `S0`. Marked objects are moved to `S1` and then `Eden` and `S0` are flattened. This is heavily simplified, but should illustrate why objects need to be moved.

Comment: @BoristheSpider What if the marked objects was statying at `S0`, and the survivors were moved from `Eden` to `S0`, what would we lose in that case?

Comment: What happens to the unmarked objects in `S0`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider They're moved to `S1`. But I don't get what if the GC stayed their back in `S0`?

Comment: Yey for fragmentation...

Answer (score 1):

This is how GC seperate variables' scope, so a variable in a class would be in S0 but when getting into a method GC is triggerd so that local variables in the method becomes S0 and the variables in the class becomes S1.
When getting out of the method, GC is triggerd again, the local variables are destroyed and the variables in the class are moved to S0 and when out of the class they are destroyed(note that variables in the class mean any variables we can reach not just static variables).

Comment: we can reach both static and instance variables in an instance method, but in a static method, only static variables are reached unless provided a parameter that references the same class.